# Tensorflow: why tf.nn.conv2d runs faster than tf.layers.conv2d?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am writing a simple implementation of AlexNet. I tried with using tf.nn.conv2d and tf.layers.conv2d, and the results turn out that the loss dropped faster when using tf.nn.conv2d, even the structure is exactly the same. Does anyone know any explanation for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to follow the chain of function calls, you will find that `tf.layers.conv2D()` makes calls to `tf.nn.conv2D()` so no matter what you use, `tf.nn.conv2d()` will be called, it will be just faster if you call it yourself. You can use `traceback.print_stack()` method to verify that for yourself.

**NOTE** This does not mean that they are one and the same, select the function based on your need as there are various other tasks undertaken by `tf.layers.conv2D()`.